# RedBeanPHP findAll: acess elements by array index

Tags: php, redbean

I am using RedBeanPHP this way:

```
$banners = R::findAll('banner');
```

After that i wanted to access each element by its index, says:

```
$banner1 = $banners[2];
```

But that way RedBeanPHP try to retrieve a banner which column id = 2 in the database table

What is the way to access elements by the index result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, array_values is the solution:

```
$banners = R::findAll('banner');
$banners = array_values($banners);
$banner1 = $banners[2];
```

Comment: Another option would be to use a `foreach` (inside PHP, of course, or maybe inside the templating engine if using one.)